# x-axis labels in barplot and expanding a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

My data

```
df <- structure(list(variable = c("main.tmin", "main.tmin", "main.tmin", 
                        "main.tmin", "main.tmin"), 
           coef = c(-23.28653023, 22.98726658, -55.1958095, -30.08524407, 
                    36.22033036), 
           acz = c(101L, 103L, 107L, 113L, 114L)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = acz, y = coef)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I want to do two things:

First I want to expand `df` to have acz from 101:114 such that for acz
which do not have any values have NA in them. Something like this

```
final.df <- data.frame(variable = "main.tmin",
                   acz = 101:114, 
                  coef = c(-23.28653, NA, 22.98727, NA, NA, NA, -55.19581, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -30.08524, 36.22033))


ggplot(final.df, aes(x = acz, y = coef)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Then I want to show all the labels on the x-axis which at the current moment 
is shown only for the selected few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill in missing range of `acz` you can use `complete` and `full_seq` functions from `tidyr`. By default they will also put `NA` for other columns.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
# Using OPs data
ggplot(complete(df, acz = full_seq(acz, 1)), 
       aes(factor(acz), coef)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

---

Another solution is to directly transform x-axis labels to discrete scale by passing range limits:

```
ggplot(df, aes(acz, coef)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = seq(min(df$acz), max(df$acz)))
```